# How do I create a people-friendly URL using an alias and ID from database?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have created a simple CMS in which each article has an id, title, alias (for URL), introtext, fulltext, etc. as:

```
create table articles (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    title varchar(80),
    alias varchar(80),
    introtext text,
    fulltext text,
    published tinyint(1),
    date date
)
```

To access an article using the ID is easy and the URL will look something like:

```
www.mysite.com/article?id=31
```

or perhaps
    www.mysite.com/article?menuid=3&id=31

In my database the article looks like:

id: 3
title: This is my life
alias: this-is-my-life
introtext: yadda ... yadda

The goal is to take the alias field and use it to create a people-friendly URL as:

```
www.mysite.com/this-is-my-life.php
```

or

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?article=this-is-my-life
```

or

```
www.mysite.com/?article=this-is-my-life
```

In any case the article id is used to obtain the alias from the table and the alias becomes the basis of the people-friendly URL.

I see this regularly done in CMS like Joomla and Wordpress, perhaps even zen-cart. The question is how do you accomplish this with a PHP script or redirect function in the .htaccess?

**New information (Jan. 23)**

We seem to be talking apples to oranges as I am not understanding how this is supposed to work. Perhaps a link to a simplified demo site where you can see the menu ID structure in action will help.

http://dottedi.us/test

This is slightly more complicated than the initial example but follows the same general idea. The live demo is based upon using the joomla menu manager to create the menu item including the URL and the optional alias. it looks like:

www.dottedi.us/test/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=5

Joomla and probably the other CMS systems (Wordpress, Drupal, etc) has a global configuration parameter to enable what they call SEO-friendly URLs. I call them people-friendly. It would take the above URL and convert it to the people friendly version employing the alias field from the table so the above URL would become

www.dottedi.us/test/about.php (with or without the .php suffix)

Rather than use the link field as the visible URL I could use the alias field so that it will look like about.php when you hover over it, but I am confused how to make it return the live URL. You can see this at:

http://dottedi.us/test2

I added some debugging output which you can see if you scroll to the bottom of a page. Does this help?

Answer (score 3):

Use mod_rewrite to create pretty URLs

To do this, create a `.htaccess` file and paste this into it. Then upload it to the index of your sites root folder.

*Quick tip*: You can create an `.htaccess` file by simply opening a text editor like Notepad (PC) or Text Edit (Mac) and then saving it as `.htaccess`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  #article rewrite
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /article.php?id=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Your URL should now look something like this:

`www.mysite.com/this-is-my-life`

**INSTEAD OF:**

`www.mysite.com/article?id=31`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the rule line-by-line? You turn on the engine, and then your conditions are that the request does not match a file or directory. But how does the rule itself work? How does a "1" turn into "this-is-my-life" without any reference to a database?

Comment: I guess you decided *not* to explain the rewrite rule?? (you deleted your comment saying you would get right on it)

Comment: I copied the .htaccess text verbatim and tested by loading several different pages and it makes no difference. I can't see why it would but I may be missing something. The alias is stored in a database table field. It seems to me that we will need to run a query against the item id (or article id) to extrapolate the alias then do some type of rewrite to the URL?

Comment: You'll have to actually go to `mysite.com/1` to see article 1. What it does is rewrites the URL from `mysite.com/article?id=1` to `mysite.com/1` @BobMeetin