# Dynamic URL based htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am stick in a situation of a websites URL. Here I am describing it using an e-commerce site.

> Product Categories

```
Women ------> womens-clothing (sub-category)
                     ---------> womens-top (child)
                     ---------> womens-dress (child)
```

`public_html` is the root directory. I want to create URLs like this -->

**Case 1 ->** If user wants to view all the products under a sub-category (say *`Womens-clothing`*). Then I want the URL to be `www.website.com/womens-clothing/(may be some parameters here)`.

**Case 2 ->** If user wants to view all the products under a specific child (say *`womens-top`* which is under `womens-clothing` sub-category) then I want the URL to be `www.website.com/womens-clothing/womens-tops/(may be some parameters here)`.

So my question is do I need to create a directory for each `sub-categories` and `child-categories` under its parent categories or it can be done with `HTACCESS` in any single page without creating directories ..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this by creating directories (while works) is almost idiotic as it would be massively time consuming and hard to manage.

Yes! `.htaccess` (where apache is concerned) is the right choice for a solution to your problem.

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

This snippet is a great example of how a `.htaccess` file can be used for this purpose.

Then, in your `index.php` file, you can get the url by `$_GET['page]`

So, say your at the page; `www.website.com/womens-clothing/womens-tops/`

The `$_GET['page]` would return `womens-clothing/womens-tops/`.

Then, just `$url = explode('/', $_GET['page]);`

`$url[0]` = `womens-clothing`

`$url[1]` = `womens-tops`

Doing this will give you your parameters.

Also, use an `if (isset($url[NUM])) {}` so you don't get errors for an out of range index.

Thats the basis of it anyway.

---

### Explanation

all this is really doing is hiding `index.php` from the url, as well as serving every ***'directory'*** in the url as a get request.

This is known as `URL Rewriting`, and involves apaches `mod_rewrite` function.

Answer (score 0):

No, Not at all! Creating a directory per URL neither is dynamic, nor applicable when your site grows. Soon your website maintenance gets overwhelming.

Solution to your problem is to keep with **URL Rewrite**(mod_rewrite for Apache web server) along with .htaccess & creating a kinda **URL Aliases**.

Consult these questions here:

[Generate URL Alias?? in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182262/generate-url-alias-in-php)

[How do I create a people-friendly URL using an alias and ID from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016688/how-do-i-create-a-people-friendly-url-using-an-alias-and-id-from-database)

Comment: Thank you, this also helped me