# .htaccess configuration for friendly URLs is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I'm trying to send values from one php page to another, but instead of the URL showing, 
example: "page2.php?values=value1/value2" 
I want:  "page2/value1/value2

This is what I have on my .htaccess:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

 RewriteRule ^page2/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ page2.php?values=$1
```

the code I use to send the data on page 1 is:

`window.location.href = "page2/" + value1 + "/" + value2;`

The URL appears "page2/value1/value2" but I get the following message (I'm using XAMPP):

*Object not located!
The requested URL has not been located on this server. The URL of the page that referred you seems to be wrong or obsolete. Please report the error to the author of that page.*

*If you believe this is a server error, please report it to the portal administrator.*

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You've added a `RewriteCond` for your _page2_ URL but you want a `RewriteRule`. I'd also move it above the other rule

Comment: And also, you might want to change the order. `page2/value1/value2` does not exist as a file or directory, but you propbably _don’t_ want that rewritten to `page2/value1/value2.php`

Comment: @Phil You were right, I hadn't noticed that I had `RewriteCond`, but even correcting it and move it above the other rule, I still don't have the result that I expect, the same message _Object not located!_ appears.

Comment: @CBroe change the order of what?

Comment: I found a solution on this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956502/dynamic-url-based-htaccess

Comment: The order in which you are doing these two things. Rewrite your page stuff first (and stop there, if that happend - `L` flag), and then add the `.php` suffix in the rest of cases, when applicable.